# Mejorar seguridad al publicar una aplicación usando FTP desde Visual Studio ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

Existe alguna forma de mejorar la seguridad al publicar una aplicación usando FTP desde Visual Studio?

Visual Studio avisa que usuario y contraseña son enviados en texto plano y los riesgos que eso implica, pero hay alguna forma de poder mejorar la seguridad? Alguna extensión disponible o algo así?